# How to install spark on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I'm in an internship position and i have a limited access to a downloads/installation in the system. My problem is how to install Apache spark on Windows 7 (Always I used it via Hortonwork into VM but in my internship i don't have a right to install VM or Hortonworks). I searched more in the forum, I Think that I can use Eclipse, import spark and install scala IDE (scala is my prefered langage with Spark) but I can't arrived to a solution.

Can you please give me any suggestion or idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I used this guide and it works just fine.

www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Spark_on_Windows10.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch a Spark job in local mode from your IDE (Eclipse or Intellij), just :

- download the IDE
- download the corresponding Scala plugin
- download the SBT plugin
- create a SBT project
- in the build.sbt add Spark dependencies :

  ```
  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
  ```

Then you can write a Scala main class named Main.scala :

```
object Main {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("HbaseWriteTest")
        .getOrCreate()

      ...
    }
}
```

Execute the Main class and it will execute the Spark job in local mode.

After if you want to run a Spark cluster on your local machine, you can follow official documentation here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: I downloaded the IDE Eclipse and scala, but when I added it by help -> install new software it dispaly many error like this :  Software being installed: Scala Search 0.2.5.v-2_11-201505250900-dd17080 (org.scala.tools.eclipse.search.feature.feature.group 0.2.5.v-2_11-201505250900-dd17080)
  Missing requirement: Scala Refactoring 0.6.3.2_11-201410271313-539abd5 (org.scala-refactoring.library 0.6.3.2_11-201410271313-539abd5) requires 'bundle org.junit 4.11.0' but it could not be found

Comment: I don't know where does it come from. Maybe you can give a try to Intellij. It is what I use for Scala/Spark and it works well.